# Need to generate records, one to many. MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have a table called testPPDS that contains my individual records. ProjectUID is unique ( although there is no enforcement of a unique key ).Environment is blank.

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ProjectUID | ProjectName | environment |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1          | Project1    |             |
| 2          | Project2    |             |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I  have another table called testMASTER that contains the environment info I need to populate the testPPDS table. It's data is below...

```
+------------+-------------+
| ProjectUID | environment |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | DEV1        |
| 1          | DEV2        |
| 2          | DEV3        |
| 2          | DEV4        |
+------------+-------------+
```

I am trying to generate a record detailing ProjectUIDs and all the environments they show up in. I would then use this SELECT to populate a new table.

```
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| ProjectUID | ProjectName | environment |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1          | Project1    |  DEV1       |
| 1          | Project1    |  DEV2       |
| 2          | Project2    |  DEV3       |
| 2          | Project2    |  DEV4       |
+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I am trying all kinds of joins to get this out there and none seem to be working. Has anyone ran across something like this before? I appreciate any advice anyone has.
JC

Comment: How would you want to handle situations where there is no TestPPDS but there are testMasters for the project or vise versa?  Or do you only care about those that exist in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT testMASTER.ProjectUID
      , testPPDS.Projectname
      , testMASTER.environment 
 FROM testMASTER 
 RIGHT JOIN testPPDS 
   ON testPPDS.ProjectUID = testMASTER.ProjectUID`

[image]

Comment: You get the answer karma Ahmed for making this a JOIN which is what I need to understand better. JW

Comment: Why a right join?  Why not a left or inner?  nothing in question indicates one over the other should be used.

Answer (score 1):

OK guys, I am practically embarrassed that I asked this one the answer was so easy. The solution I discovered is below...

```
SELECT testPPDS.ProjectUID, testPPDS.ProjectName, testMASTER.environment 
FROM testPPDS, testMASTER 
WHERE testPPDS.ProjectUID = testMASTER.ProjectUID;
```

I'll leave this here as help for others and a monument to my idiocy.

JW

Comment: Consider using `FROM TESTPPDS INNER JOIN testMaster ON testPPDS.ProjectUID = testMASTER.ProjectUID`  many indicate `,` in a from clause is the old method of joins and more difficult to maintain especially when using outer joins.